# Json_encode rejects characters in string

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

Within the array that I retrieve from mysql is a text field that contains an ellipsis as part of the entry.  While mysqli will print out the array record properly, when I try to encode it to a json string (json_encode), I get an error...actually nothing happens.  At this point I know enough about json to be dangerous.  Hopefully somebody has an answer to this. In the meantime I found the offending records and have changed the ellipsis (...) to colon-minus (:-) which seems to work. For presentation sake, I'd like to include the ellipsis.

Thanks,
KCT3937

Comment: Can you share your code please? Otherwise it will be pretty much impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

"At this point I know enough about json to be dangerous." as well so my suggestion is to work around the problem if you can't find a "proper" solution.

Replace the offending character with something else before encoding and replace it back to the ellipsis in the JavaScript that receives the response.

If you are using php you may also want to look into JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE. Check the json_encode online manual for more details.

Another thing to check is verify that your data is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: why JavaScript appear in your response? :-)